# How to remove permalinks links presents in each page of my site?

Tags: theme-development, permalinks, themes, admin, options

I have this WordPress static site: http://www.saranistri.com/

As you can see at the end of each page there is a link named **Pemalink** into a box.

I want to remove this box and this link. Can I do this operation directly from the WordPress backend or have I to remove it directly from the code of my template?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in 2 ways:

**Remove it from HTML source code** (harder, but more correct)

Find `<footer class="post-meta">` in your theme files, and remove (or comment) it (with contents). You will see something like this in one of your files:

```
<footer class="post-meta">
    ...
    <a href="...</a>
    ...
</footer>
```

Just remove this part of code or comment it. (Of course don't forget to backup these files before modyfying them).

**Hide it with CSS**

To do it, just add this:

```
footer.post-meta {
    display: none;
}
```

to your CSS file.